# Boot order in BIOS settings (Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD) resets back to default after restarting twice

Tags: linux, bios

I've been trying to boot Linux off of my USB drive for a while now. The sequence of steps I followed and the results I got are as written below:

**Step 1:** Insert USB (with installed Linux) into the slot and go into BIOS settings. Once there, I change the boot order so that USB is placed at the top.

**Step 2:** I save the settings and then exit the setup.

**Step 3:** Boots from USB successfully. I shutdown and remove the USB from the slot.

Step 4: I reboot laptop without touching BIOS settings. It boots Windows 10. I shutdown and all is good up to this point.

**Step 5:** I insert Linux USB again and turn computer on. This time it boots Windows again.

I go to check what happened with the BIOS settings and I see that my USB is placed third in the boot order (as in the default case).

Why is this happening? Is there a way to boot Linux from USB whenever the Linux USB is inserted?

Thanks for the all the help in advance.

PS: I see that a similar question was posted (here: [Laptop unable to boot up after changing boot order in BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/985344/laptop-unable-to-boot-up-after-changing-boot-order-in-bios)) but the problem wasn't solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS changes the boot order because you keep changing the physical devices available. If you never remove the USB drive and boot into Windows by selecting it from the boot menu manually, it will continue to keep the boot order. Once you remove that device the BIOS says "Well that doesn't exist anymore, here are the available boot devices now" and shifts the USB drive off the list. Then when you re-insert the USB drive it says "Oh look a new boot device, I'll keep that at the end of the list since it's a new device and has never been setup previously"